# Oracle database: getting time from total amount of minutes from the beginning of a day

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

Given - number of minutes (number oracle type) from the beginning of a day, e.g. 480. Need to get standard oracle time, e.g. - 08:00:00 AM. Is there any good functions to do such operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add minutes/1440 to the date, e.g.

```
select to_date('1.1.2015','dd.mm.yyyy')+480/1440 from dual;
```

Answer (score 5):

Better use **INTERVAL 'minutes' MINUTE** to add the number of minutes. Easy to understand.

```
your_date_time + INTERVAL '480' MINUTE
```

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE), TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '480' MINUTE tmstamp FROM dual;

TRUNC(SYSDATE)      TMSTAMP
------------------- -------------------
11/19/2015 00:00:00 11/19/2015 08:00:00
```

In fact, another way which is independent of **NLS** settings when you have to pass the date as literal. Thus, instead of using **TO_DATE**, use the **ANSI Date literal** which uses a fixed format `'YYYY-MM-DD'` and is **NLS** independent.

```
SQL> SELECT DATE '2015-11-19' curr_date, DATE '2015-11-19' + INTERVAL '480' MINUTE tmstamp 
2    FROM dual;

CURR_DATE           TMSTAMP
------------------- -------------------
11/19/2015 00:00:00 11/19/2015 08:00:00
```

---

**UDPATE**

> Given - number of minutes (number oracle type) from the beginning of a day, e.g. 480

If the **minutes** value is not static in SQL to be hard-coded, but a **PL/SQL** variable, then as @AlexPoole mentioned you need to use **NUMTODSINTERVAL**.

For example,

```
NUMTODSINTERVAL(480, 'MINUTE')
```

Having said that,

The Oracle PL/SQL `NUMTODSINTERVAL` function converts an input number to its specified Interval Day to Second Unit equivalent. The allowed interval units can be DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, or SECOND.

**The return type of the function is INTERVAL**.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL(480, 'MINUTE') intrvl FROM DUAL;

INTRVL    
---------------------------------------------------------------------    
+000000000 08:00:00.000000000
```

Comment: The question suggests the number of minutes is a variable ("number oracle type") so you'd need to use `numtodsinterval()` rather than an interval literal?

Comment: @AlexPoole hmm..well I don't see OP mentioned it to be a variable value. OP just mentioned it is **number** type. I added an update as per your suggestion. Thanks for sharing your thought :-)